# Swift - Detecting an unspecified Interface style

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to be able to read if the current app appearance is set to unspecified. When clicking on the desire table view cell, the appearance is properly set where changing the appearance of device mimics with the app. However I cannot find a way to read the value of appearance to be: light/dark/unspecified. Only light/dark. Upon reading some more I read this below.

> The trait collection contains a complete set of trait values
> describing the current environment, and does not include unspecified
> or unknown values.

I need to check if the appearance is unspecified in other parts and I was curious if anyone had ideas on how to check. Here is a snippet of what I have, below is a helper function

```html
        let appearanceMap = [Appearance.device, Appearance.light, Appearance.dark]

        switch appearanceMap[indexPath.row] {
        case .light:
            UIApplication.shared.changeInterfaceStyle(.light)
        case .dark:
            UIApplication.shared.changeInterfaceStyle(.dark)
        case .device:
            UIApplication.shared.changeInterfaceStyle(.unspecified)
        }
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
                      let keyWindow = appDelegate.window else { return }
        let currentAppearance = keyWindow.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle
        print(currentAppearance.stringValue)
```

```html
extension UIApplication {
    func changeInterfaceStyle(_ mode: UIUserInterfaceStyle) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
              let keyWindow = appDelegate.window else { return }
        keyWindow.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = mode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use this instead

```
if UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .unspecified {
        print("unspecified")
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).